# AMD/DTI Radeo HD 5450 SUpported?

Tags: ati, catalyst

I have a XFX HD 5450 based card I would like to install on my desktop running Ubuntu 13.04. The opensource drive doesn't implement 3D acceleration, making it impractical for Unity/Compiz.

I followed the (very good) instructions in this link to install the latest Catalyst https://askubuntu.com/a/286775/35775. After reboot, the system freezes on the greeting screen. It doesn't even give me a chance to open a console. The only document solution I didn't try was the "sudo aticonfig --tls=0"

Before I go again through the whole marathon of card and drive installation, is there any evidence of a working HD 5450 out there?

Comment: Have you tried installing via Additional Drivers Tab in Software Sources?

Answer (score 0):

Not having any problems here

[image]

I am using the xorg-edgers fresh X crack ppa as found [here](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa)

Performance within 13.04 has been very good